# how can I read text from a .txt and save it as a string in a variable?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Ive made many efforts to try to find an answer on the internet about how using XMLHttpRequest I can save what I read in a variable, but I haven't succeeded. All the code I've been given ends with the responseText being sent as a console.log... and won't scape the function scope of the xhr.onload. If I try to save the text in a variable, it is only locally saved in the function of the xhr.onload, and can't save it in a permanent variable so I can use it later in another way.
Something very simple and trivial can't find the solution to it...

please help!

Comment: instead of storing in a file why can't you store in global variable/

Comment: you can also use sessionStorage or localStorage based upon your requirement

Comment: im not trying to store anything on a file...I want to store the text from a file in a variable with global scope...I can't use session or local storage, and neither shouldn't I....why wouldn't I do something so trivial as saving an external text in a variable? there must be something I can do...

Comment: so for global scope use Global variables or sessionStorage or localStorage

Comment: when I try to make it global variables, it says I need to use TypeScript

Comment: you can use sessionStorage or localStorage as well

Comment: The error you mention that you need typescript is weird.

Comment: I find amazing that something so simple as saving text in a variable is seems to be IMPOSIBLE....omG